# Distribute 1 Pub/Sub Topic Messages across multiple Cloud Functions without repetition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have 8 Cloud functions that are triggered by a Pub/Sub topic.

Example problem:
When 16 messages are published to the Pub/Sub topic, all 8 functions are triggered, and each of the 8 functions receives all 16 messages.

Desired outcome:
When 16 messages are published to the Pub/Sub topic, all 8 functions are triggered, each of the 8 functions should receive **only 2** messages.

Is there a way to solve this?

I tried: setup 1 pub/sub topic, 1 pub/sub subscription, trigger 8 functions from that 1 subscription, but in yaml documentation and in the cloud console it appears I can only have a function triggered from a topic, not an existing subscription.

Possible but not desired solution:
Load balance the (example) 16 messages across 8 different pub/sub topics, then each function gets triggered by 1/8 topics (2 messages per topic).

Answer (score 1):

It's an anti-pattern to have 8 separate Cloud Functions over which you want to load balance messages. If the code is identical for each one, then you should really only have a single Cloud Function and let its autoscaling behavior take care of turning up instances as needed to handle the incoming messages.

If the 8 Functions have different code, then it's counter-intuitive that you want each to only handle a subset of the messages unless you want them routed to the functions based on some property of the messages themselves, in which case you'd want to set up 8 subscriptions that use [filters](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter).

If the behavior you seek is truly what you need, then you may need to put a separate Cloud Function in between that receives all messages and distributes it to other Cloud Functions that instead of using Pub/Sub as a trigger, use an HTTP request. Then, you could make the HTTP request from the single function that receives Pub/Sub messages and distribute them as needed across the other 8 functions.

Comment: Just to provide some clarity on your first comment - the reason for having 8 separate identical Cloud Functions is to create a multi-regional setup

Comment: In that case, you may want to consider moving to the pull model, which allows you to have subscribers wherever you want and for them to share the load. However, even with that, Pub/Sub will prefer to deliver to the network-nearest region if it has capacity and won't necessarily divide the load evenly over all of the instances.